# How can I be %100 sure that writing to a text file has been finished in C#, so that I can proceed with another operation?

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

In my C# project, i have to write some info to a file with streamwriter, and afterwards I want to call a method. But I have to be % 100 sure that the writing process has been finished, otherwise a data inconsistency can occure. How can I check this in my program?

Comment: Flush the stream, Close/ Dispose it, Close the file. It's done. It's possible that the write to disk may not be complete (because the OS provides asynchrony and caching), but, to consumers of the OS, it will appear done

Comment: ^^ And if you want to be very strict about it, you try to read the file and verify the expected content is there.

Answer (score 2):

After the dispose/using block of the StreamWriter object is called without an exception you can be sure that the string has been written to file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file

```
try
{
    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine("C:\Temp", "WriteLines.txt"), true))
    {
        outputFile.WriteLine("Fourth Line");
    }

    //Text is 100% written
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 //Text might not be written
}
```